# Launch Notification type extension in Sony Smartwatch2

Tags: android, sony, sony-smartwatch

Using Control.Intents.CONTROL_START_REQUEST_INTENT, I can start other control type extension from my app, but I can't launch extension with Notification type.

Is there a way to launch extension which is Notification type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Launching a Notification extension from a Control extension is not possible unfortunately.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I hope it will be added in future release since there are requests from user who wants to launch those types of extension.